# Build Failure: How can I resolve a React Native iOS virtual device app build failure, failing CompileSwift and CompileC?

Tags: ios, c, swift, react-native

My setup:

- MacBook Pro (Early 2011)
- macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6)
- React Native (7.18.1)
- XCode (10.1)
- iOS virtual device is a iPhone 8 - 12.1
- Command Line Tools (Xcode 10.1 (10B61))
- Homebrew (3.1.12)
- node (16.3.0)
- watchman (2020.8.17)
- cocoapods (1.10.1)

I am basically new to programming, just starting to learn React Native. Trying to get my development environment set up on an old MacBook Pro.

I am following the process described here https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup on the React Native site.

And I have also been trying to do this learning project from Traversy Media here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hf4MJH0jDb4 but I realized the React Native tutorial and the Traversy Media tutorial conflict when it comes to instructing me to do a global install of the react-native-cli. I believe I currently do not have a global install of the react-native-cli, but I *could* be wrong.

I can successfully initiate an app through the terminal (i.e. generate the files into folder locations). But I get an error when starting the iOS project build onto a virtual iOS device.

I call the directory of the project.

I run:

```
npx react-native start
```

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

And then I get:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65.
```

...and then a long way down the Terminal window, after lots of lines I don't understand, I am told that the CompileSwift and CompileC commands failed:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/[myusername]/Desktop/Dev/ShoppingList/ios/Pods/YogaKit/YogaKit/Source/YGLayoutExtensions.swift
    CompileC /Users/[myusername]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShoppingList-drihumjcjrxnoqcutvskvcmaocen/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/VirtualEventBase.o /Users/[myusername]/Desktop/Dev/ShoppingList/ios/Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/io/async/VirtualEventBase.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
```

Like I said, I am completely new to programming and to React Native so any input on resolving this environment setup issue would be so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

React Native 0.64 required Xcode **12**

https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/03/12/version-0.64

Comment: With this old MacBook Pro, Xcode 10.1 is the newest version it can run, unfortunately. Do I have any capability to write and deploy React Native applications with this old setup? Sounds like the AppStore won't even accept builds from Xcode before version 12.0?

Comment: For studying you can search version react native with your configuration https://archive.reactnative.dev/versions But you can't release in AppStore